# C# multilevel inheritance or duplicated implementation of interfaces?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

It seems that technically, there is no limit in the number of multilevel inheritance. Example: class D inherits class C that inherits class B that inherits class A. However their names start getting complicated as you keep inheriting.

It seems to me that, in fact, having a base class and using interfaces would be a better approach.

The problem that I have is that, with interfaces, I have to implement the properties in every class. Using a base class, I implement them in only one place.

In my scenario I have the following:

- Base Class: `Animal`
- Interfaces: `RankeableByLevel` (this has additional properties that allow animals to be ranked), `FilterableByExpertise` (this has additional properties that allow animals to be filtered).

There are 10-15 `Animal` subclasses, and around 7-8 that would be rankeable and/or filterable. I don't want to implement the interfaces in each of 7-8 classes (too much "duplication" in my opinion).

One option would be to create a base class called `AnimalRankeableByLevel` and another `AnimalRankeableByLevelAndFilterableByExpertise` by specially this last one seems too long to be right!

With interfaces, I'd have to "duplicate" implementation too much.
With inheriting too many classes, it would look wrong (too long name, too many inheritings).

What would be the solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: Wrap the duplicate implementations into a class and delegate the interface calls to it.

Comment: [Prefer composition in place of inheritance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: @Lennart Thank you, would you be able to provide an example, including how would you name (if there is a naming convention) of the class that implements the properties of the interface?

Comment: You might also be interested that as of C# 8 you can provide a default implementation for an interface

Comment: This is known as "multilevel inheritance", not "nested base classes". A nested class is one that is declared INSIDE another class (and is often not visible outside the containing class)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks, adjusted to the correct term.

Comment: When you say *"with interfaces, I have to implement the properties in every class"*, do you mean you just don't want to have to define the properties (i.e. `public string Level { get; set; }`), or is it that you have actual duplicated code in the implementation of the interface methods that you don't want to have to re-write for each animal?

Comment: @RufusL I would say both. But for this question, you can consider the first one (defining properties in each class). I wish interface could declare actual fields instead of just properties.

Comment: Well you have to add the interface implementation (or inherit from a class that does), but visual studio makes that pretty easy with a single click. Then for actual duplicated code, you could do as Lennart suggested in the first comment, where all classes that share a particular implementation would just redirect method calls to a common class.

Comment: @igorjrr  For example: you have some kind of calculation how an animal is ranked, and this calculation is very similar between animals. Create a "calculator" class that contains that calculation, and in each animal class with RankeableByLevel simply return the values calculated by that class for a property. For example `public int Rank => rankCalculator.CalculateRank()`. You can't avoid the duplication of the interface implementation (which is ok btw), but you can delegate the concrete calculation to a common class (which can also be easier tested).

Comment: @Lennart and RufusL if one of youcould please submit it as answer, I can mark as answered. This is what I needed to know and good to share to others who have similar question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favor composition over inheritance. Implementing an interface in 7-8 classes is not per se an issue.

If you want to reduce the duplication of the interface implementations (because e.g. the calculation of certain values is similar) you can extract that calculation to another class and delegate the interface implementations to that class.

Example:

```
public class SomeAnimal : IRankable
{
  private IRankingCalculator calculator = new RankingCalculator();

  public int Rank => calculator.GetRank();

  //...
}
```

```
public interface IRankable
{
   public int Rank {get;}
}
```